# Python - How to add Menu in VIEW3D_HT_header?

Tags: python

I want to add `Menu` in `VIEW3D_HT_header`

after `VIEW3D_MT_object`

before `VIEW3D_PT_transform_orientations` and after `VIEW3D_PT_proportional_edit`

before `VIEW3D_PT_object_type_visibility`

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can with regular python API, at least without resorting to dark unstable magick. However if you append a menu to `VIEW3D_MT_object` you'll have an entry between object and transform menus.

Answer (score 1):

What @[Gorgious](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86891/gorgious) said in a comment.  More specifically, you *can* add a menu to the header by writing a draw routine and then calling

```py
bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_header.append(YOUR_DRAW_ROUTINE)
```

*but* it will appear as the last item in the header.  You can use `prepend` rather than `append` but then it will appear first.

If you want to see an example of the *dark unstable magick* that's usually used to accomplish adding menus in the middle, take a look at the source for [HardOps](https://github.com/mx1001/hops_p) which does such a thing.  It's not for the faint of heart and it breaks easily.

Best to figure out which of the existing menus your new entry would be most suited to and add it to that menu, as @Gorgious suggested.