# Adding items to VIEW3D_HT_tool_header **after** existing settings/tools

Tags: python

I know how to append and prepend any draw items or operators to the tool_header section:

```
def draw_test(self, context):
    """Draw in tool_header test"""
    layout = self.layout
    column = layout.column()
    column.label(text="Test me")

bpy.types.VIEW3D_HT_tool_header.prepend(draw_test)
```

[image]

But I would like to draw my items **after** any existing items, or even completely overwrite the tool_header while my operator is running modal:

[image]

I'm struggling to figure this out

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255025/python-how-to-add-menu-in-view3d-ht-header

Comment: @scurest Adding to an existing menu is easy enough in the HEADER, but the menus in TOOL_HEADER keep changing with what tool you have selected which makes this method much more difficult. I've been looking at the CAD Transform addon which adds it's settings to the tool_header but it seems that it does this only because it's a tool registered in the tool bar. I'd like to add, or even completely overwrite the tool_header when my operator is called and running modal